# How to access data submitted by a form in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms

Here is an example from `Ng-Book - the Complete Book on Angularjs
Book by Ari Lerner` http://jsbin.com/voxirajoru/edit?html,output where `ng-form` has been used to create nested form elements and perform validation. As the each input field has same value for `name` attribute so how can on the server side I can access value of all three variables by using some server side language? Let's say it's `PHP` and `method` is `post`. Usually in `PHP` I would do this:

```
`$_POST['dynamic_input']`
```

but how is it possible to access three field values coming from input field using `$_POST` array?

Comment: All those fields you're talking about have their own ids. I mean, you should retrieve them from the $_POST var by index: $_POST['name1'], $_POST['name2'], $_POST['name3'] (Where name, name2 and name3 are values of inputs' name attributes).

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` in php file you will undrestand how get that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example from the link you provided, you can access form data by updating the code there with the following.

// Add the fields object as a parameter to submitForm()

```
<form name="signup_form" ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="submitForm(fields)" novalidate>
```

// In the $scope.submitForm() function...

```
$scope.submitForm = function(data) {
    alert(data[0].name); // Alerts name
    alert(data[1].name); // Alerts password
    alert(data[2].name); // Alerts email
  };
```

If you log out the data received by submitForm(), you get the following:

```
[{"placeholder":"Username","isRequired":true,"$$hashKey":"004","name":"random name"},{"placeholder":"Password","isRequired":true,"$$hashKey":"005","name":"password"},{"placeholder":"Email (optional)","isRequired":false,"$$hashKey":"006","name":"email@host.com"}]
```

For passing to your server, package all this up as is or format it to your preference and send it to your server via the built in `$http.post()` or `$resource()` inside of the $scope.submitForm function.

An example of the formatted data could be:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(data) {
    var postData = {};
    postData.name = data[0].name;
    postData.password = data[1].name;
    postData.email = data[2].name;

    ... send postData to server via AJAX ...

    // Creates the object: {"name":"random name","password":"password","email":"email@host.com"}
    //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
  };
```